# Read DB function - execution order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a DB and output the result in a string.
The issue is that sometimes the output is empty, my guess is that the function "json" is executed before the DB-read is completed.. I tried to apply "callback" which I read in other threads, but it didnt solve it.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var response = {};
var items = {};
var table = "table";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
ReadDB(json);
return response;
};

//**********************ReadDB Function
function ReadDB(callback) {
var paramsRead = {
  TableName: table,
};

// Call DB to read the item from the table
ddb.scan(paramsRead, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error reading DynamoDB", err);
  } else {
      items = data.Items;
  }
});

callback(items);

}

//**********************json Function
function json(items) {
  console.log(items);
    response = {
      body: JSON.stringify({items}, null, '\t'),
        };
        console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is called asynchronious. This is the relevant bit:

```
// Call DB to read the item from the table
ddb.scan(paramsRead, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error reading DynamoDB", err);
  } else {
      items = data.Items;
  }
});

callback(items);
```

You likely expect that `ddb.scan()` fires and completes, *then* `callback()`. But the scan function is async, which (simply put) it doest block the remaining code.
You should read this code as: `ddb.scan()` is *started* and then then `callback()` is *started*. The `.scan()` is practically always slower, thus no result.

In your example, you have the data in your else, this is where you trigger `callback(data.Item)`, as that code is on the *revolve* of the `.scan()` function.

---

Promises are a tricky concept to wrap your head around in the beginning, I suggest you do some research. Controling promises is difficult in the beginning, but understanding the basics is doable.

[Suggested reading material I found by Googling "*javascript simple promises explanation*"](https://blog.cloudboost.io/explaining-basic-javascript-promises-in-jip-en-janneketaal-c98763c0abd6)

Comment: Thank you for your great reply! I have tried to put callback(items) under else-section, but this cause the "return response" to execute and return an empty json?

Comment: Same issue as explained above, but then with `ReadDB` and `return` :) You could add a "async" to the ReadDB function, and an await in the call. Thats also someyou you can Google.